# with ActiveTcl8.5.14 and Python 2.7, what are good online resources?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to write my first program using Tkinter and python 2.7. The Tkinter library I have installed is: ActiveTcl8.5.14. My question is: What is a good online resource for this combination? I have been making progress by trial and error, but now I'm stuck. I'm trying to set a stringVar to a file name. But I'm concerned that I'm using code that is for the wrong version of Python or Tkinter.

```
def abrir_capitulo():
    ##Dialog box for selecting the chapter to be loaded.
    import tkFileDialog
    WORDLIST_FILENAME = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(mode='r',parent=master,title="Archivo para abrir")
```

This is the traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1470, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/Users/Noel/Documents/Professional Development/MIT CS 6.0/Recall Game/Recall_Game.py", line 103, in abrir_capitulo
    WORDLIST_FILENAME = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(mode='r',parent=master,title="Archivo para abrir")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/tkFileDialog.py", line 125, in askopenfilename
    return Open(**options).show()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/tkCommonDialog.py", line 48, in show
    s = w.tk.call(self.command, *w._options(self.options))
TclError: bad option "-mode": must be -defaultextension, -filetypes, -initialdir, -initialfile, -message, -multiple, -parent, -title, -typevariable, or -command
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [askopenfilename documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm), askopenfilename does not have `mode` parameter.

```
WORDLIST_FILENAME = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename(parent=master,title="Archivo para abrir")
```

See http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter for documentations.